# How can I find out why a server rebooted?

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2

My server rebooted and I am not sure why.  Is there a way to find out, e.g. perhaps someone did it manually, or as a result of a windows update or a blue screen?

I've looked in the Event Viewer, but I am not sure what to look for - there are million items there.

Comment: Every event has a related Event ID. In the future, all you need to do is search the web for the ID of the event in question (in this case, a shutdown), and filter the log for that ID.

Answer (score 29):

You want to filter for Event ID 1074 in the System logs. That's the ID for shutdown.

If it wasn't a clean shutdown, you're going to have to [sort through the memory dumps](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/315263).

Comment: A nice tool to view the dump files: http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/blue_screen_view.html